# appear any temp disk space issues with unlink()?

Tags: php

When using `unlink()` in PHP on a `linux` server, the file gets deleted.

Is it really deleted or are there any `temp` files or get the file copied in some directory like a "php-trash"?

So that the server will run into trouble over sometime (no disk space available)?

Is `unlink()` limited to the size of the file? (I want to unlink files over 100 megabyte)

Comment: `unlink()` on a linux server means the file is immediately deleted and its space freed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unlink()` is generally the best you can do to delete a file from within a PHP script, as it utilizes the operating system's underlying deletion functions.  Whether the file actually gets deleted or stored in a temporary "Trash" folder of some sort, is down to the server's file system and configuration; it should never be your concern.

`unlink()` has no size limit for what kinds of files it can delete.

Answer (score 2):

`unlink` in PHP simply calls the operating system's `unlink` operation, so it does whatever a similar C program would do.